# Secure method to execute a script remotely with ssh

Tags: linux, ssh

I woud like to I'd like to allow a user to connect to a server using SSH and execute a script, and nothing else. how can I do to that ? how can I secure it ?

thanks you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make that script the user's shell.

Answer (score 0):

SSH is already secure, make sure you use token based authentication and eliminate password based access.

---

OK, now I think I got you wrong. I thought you were asking securily connecting.

To allow, user to just execute the shell script. Create a non-root, non-sudoer user and permit him to execute the shell script. http://www.dartmouth.edu/~rc/help/faq/permissions.html

Answer (score 0):

(I think this is more appropriate for serverfault.com).

Anyways, to answer your question, look up "ssh command keys".